# ORA-01723 zero-length columns are not allowed - Creating a table from view

Tags: database, oracle

I am getting zero-length columns are not allowed when Creating a table from view

create table table < view_name > as select * from < view_name >;

seems like some of the columns are represented as varchar(0) -I guess when the column is empty?

I was Goggling this and it seems that the solution is to change the view to cast the data for the problematic column,

 The thing is that I don't have access to the views so I cannot change them

Is it possible to overcome this ORA-01723  without changing the view?

Comment: yes - just be explicit instead of saying SELECT *

Comment: There are tons of views, so specify each and every one of them will consume a lot of time....

Comment: well, thats how you would do it.  you may consider writing a script to generate the statements from the data dictionary - bu tthen balance whether this one time effort is worth that scripting effort, or just do it